# Can I use an ethernet module (or an USB connection) for light communication?

Tags: microcontroller, led, usb, ethernet, light

I'd like to transmit data (e.g. copy a file between two computers) at high speed via light. I found lots of examples around the web but mostly the speed is really slow because a serial connection (like from GPIO pins) is used. 
Here is an example:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Data-Over-Light-a-Laser-Modem-Prototype/
I also found the Ronja project, though it seems also to be not that fast.

While searching I came across this neat device: 
http://www.waveshare.com/lan8720-eth-board.htm and I thought why I just cant connect a lan cable to the rj45 port and use the RMII pins to transmit data (e.g. toggle a led on and off via TX0 and TX1). 
There must be some way to do this because media converters can also convert electric to optical signals and vice versa.
Also a USB connection could be quite fast but I'm not sure how the NRZI encoding would influence data transmission.

Comment: Have you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li-Fi ? Now consider that that several groups of very clever people at universities are working on this. If what you propose is possible why would it take all these people to come up with solutions that are obviously more complex than yours ?

Comment: have you looked at irda?

Comment: fakemoustache Because media converters exist since years , are rather cheap and support easily speeds in the gbps region (though I don't need such a high speed). The main difference is that LiFi is non-fiber but I don't see a reason why the ethernet/usb to led "data conversion" wouldn't work in the same way. And this is what my question is exactly about.     @dwelch    I also found irda but the commercial devices only support something like 4 mbps at best (iirc). There are other standards like UFIR with ca 100 mbps speed. But I couldn't find any commercial devices for that.

Comment: [TOSLINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK) transceiver modules are easily obtained.

Comment: @hannobinder   I also read about TOSLINK. I always thought it was rather slow, though I found some more or less expensive transceivers which support 250 mbps.  I could also buy a normal fiber optic transceiver. But the main problem is still, how to get the data into the transceiver.

Comment: You can get 100base-fx fiber optic modules for compatible 100mbps ethernet equipments/switches (for tens of dollars). Now how to do away with the fiber optic cable? The issues of line-of-sight, aim, dispersion, etc... apparently have left this without any practical application (of any significance).

Comment: Define "high speed".

Comment: @RespawnedFluff 10-100 mbps

Answer (score 1):

You are mostly out of luck for wanting a tech that has been a market failure in the last decade, namely IrDA [IrPHY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_Data_Association#IrPHY).

- VFIR: 16 Mbit/s
- UFIR: 96 Mbit/s
- GigaIR: 512 Mbit/s – 1 Gbit/s

There were commercial IC [announcements for VFIR 11 years ago, e.g. SigmaTel STIR4220](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1293744), but you'll be hard pressed to find one today I think; it's been [discontinued](http://www.freescale.com/products/archived/irda:STIR42X) after Freescale bought the company that originally made it. [Datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets2/68/68974_1.pdf). There was also a [poorly named] [ASDL-7021](http://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/media/service/Publications/IrDA%20Solutions%20Selection%20Guide_080603.pdf) by Lite-On but it's [also discontinued](http://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Lite-On/ASDL-7021/?qs=bTXCcn78Sd7qanOd5HWBsg%3d%3d). [Datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/324007/LITEON/ASDL-7021.html). For the actual transceivers, there were parts like Vishay [TFDU8108](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Vishay%20Semiconductors/tfdu8108.pdf). Also [not made anymore](http://www.ttieurope.com/object/product-vsh-pcn-122710).

UFIR doesn't look like it turned into any products. Ok, Sharp [made some diodes for it](http://www.sharp.co.jp/corporate/rd/22/pdf/87-04.pdf) at least in their lab.

For GigaIR [Fraunhofer would happily sell you an eval kit](http://www.ipms.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/ipms/common/products/WMS/Irda/giga-ir-evalkit-e.pdf) but I think you'd be shocked at the sticker price.

As for

> I thought why I just cant connect a lan cable to the rj45 port and use the RMII pins to transmit data (e.g. toggle a led on and off via TX0 and TX1)

TIAS: Try It And See. Have you considered the receiver side? That's where the complicated part usually lies in consumer IR anyway. Even a basic IR remote receiver has a fair bit of stuff in it, even though it's a just a 3-pin device. And it [uses a carrier](https://youtu.be/BUvFGTxZBG8?t=484).

Oh, and 100Mbit Ethernet on copper (100BASE-TX) uses [3 voltage levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MLT-3_encoding). How is your LED going to blink that? For fiber transmission 100Mbit Ethernet uses a different PHY encoding. For just 10Mbit, you might be able to pull it off since only two voltage levels are used [by the Manchester encoding]... assuming you can find an optical receiver for that speed, but then it's not that far off from the 4Mbit IrDA that you can still buy and will just work. Also, beware that for the 10Mbit Ethernet transceiver to recognize a peer it must get a link test pulse (LTP) with certain analog characteristics. If you don't use an actual twisted-pair cable as load, the LTP signal put out by an Ethernet transceiver looks pretty different; see page 3 in [this Agilent note](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5989-7528EN.pdf). The bottom line is you have your work cut out for you if you want to fool a copper Ethernet transceiver to work over some other medium, even at 10Mbit.

And regarding [Ethernet] media converters; those don't just turn electrical into optical, they do PHY encoding conversion as well. But then you could just buy 100BASE-FX/100BASE-SX/100BASE-BX devices as all a converter would do is add cost. None of these have been tested without fiber, and I strongly doubt they would work even over very short distances in air. A bit of googling fails to find an "cool hacks" in this respect, and I suspect people might have tried... and failed.

Probably your best bet is to [aggregate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation) several 4Mbit IrDA FIR connections; chips for these are still made and sold, e.g. [RPM973-H11E2A](http://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/ROHM-Semiconductor/RPM973-H11E2A/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvAL21a%2fDhxMnbn68P5stxfhxqWmjYn8VE%3d). I know nothing about interference these might cause with each other though. Or give up on this idea and use wireless like everyone else.

Since 2011, there's also an [IEEE 802.15.7 standard "Short-Range Wireless Optical Communication Using Visible Light"](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.15.7-2011.html), supporting up to [96Mb/sec](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MCOM.2012.6163585) but I don't know of any commercial products based on that. The latest cool kid is [Li-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li-Fi). Again some papers, trade-show demos, but no real commercial products you could buy at newegg... yet. And I don't have a crystal ball.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [RONJA Project](http://ronja.twibright.com/about.php) for some background on how it can be done.

They offer a complete, free design which provides a 10 Mbps full duplex link, using LEDs and other non-exotic components. Construction doesn't look too complicated - three PCBs and about 100 components.

The site presents a complete design without too much of the reasoning, but as it's been optimised for performance and ease of construction, you can read into it some of the challenges you'll face designing your own system, or extending this one.

Answer (score 0):

There's an Ethernet standard which does just what you want - [1000BASE-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet#1000BASE-X). It supports the transmission of Gigabit Ethernet signals via several kinds of fiber optic media using infrared LED or LASER transmitters. Typical transmission distances are in range of 5-50 km.

Devices implementing this standard are quite expesive though. I don't quite understand why you would want this at home. Copper wire Gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T) works for cable length up to 100 meters, more than enough for personal use.

Comment: I do not need such a high speed. 100 mbps would be sufficient. But a non-fiber connection would be required and the main problem is to make the LED understand the data from an ethernet or usb connection.

Comment: Copper and light/RF media don't use the same physical encoding of signals. You can't just attach a LED to Ethernet or USB twisted pair and expect it to work, your signal will be polluted by ambient light and reflections.

Comment: I am well aware of the different encoding. This is the main problem here. How do I encode the data from usb or the ethernet module so that the LED can understand it and is toggled on and off.

Answer (score 0):

100BASE-T ethernet uses a complex encoding scheme on the wire with multiple levels of encoding, 1000BASE-T is even worse. You can find the full details in IEEE 802.3 but suffice it to say building a decoder from scratch would not be a project I would want to attempt. You could buy an ethernet phy chip that would do the decoding work for you but those chips are still complex beasts. I guess you could probablly hook up a fiber phy to a twisted pair phy somehow but it would likely require a nontrivial ammount of work to get it working even with it's intended application of optical fiber

But it gets worse. Free space optics is a very different beast from fibre optics. With fiber optics you have a strong signal and virtually no interference, with free space even with a line of sight laser you have a much weaker signal and much more inteference. Building a decoder that can succesfully read that at 100 megabits per second is likely to be quite an undertaking in it's own right. With just an LED your signal to noise ratio is frankly going to be terrible unless your transmitter is the whole room lighting.